# vertical align text and image in ionic header

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have this code to align the title and image in the ionic header bar:

CSS:

```
.banner-top {
  background-color: #EE7130;
  height: 19.6vw;
}
.banner-top h2 {
  font-family: "JEMBOhands", sans-serif;
  font-size: 9vw;
  color: white;
#s_back {
  margin-left: 3.4vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Markup

```
  <a href="#/list" nav-transition="none"><ion-header-bar class="banner-top" align-title="left">
    <h2 id="s_back"><img src="img/back_b.png" id="s_back_img"alt="">STORIES</h2>
  </ion-header-bar></a>
```

It looks soso in the browser:

[image]

And like this on the device:

[image]

What is my mistake?
Here is a ionic play: http://play.ionic.io/app/b3660e2f6a0c

> UPDATE: It's working now in ionic play but is still wrong in the iOS simulator.. http://play.ionic.io/app/bb1620290ea4

Comment: Set CSS for `#s_back_img` as `height: 100%;`.

Comment: i have to decrease the size of the image. Now it's `height: 6.7vw;`

Comment: Default height of bar in ionic is 44px. So, set image height to 44px.

Comment: i have to use a custom height for the header bar.

Comment: Then set height of the bar as height of the img

Comment: Any code pen, plunker or fiddle will help for better understanding your problem.

Comment: Here you go: http://play.ionic.io/app/b3660e2f6a0c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Oliver: I have checked your code and saw the style for s_back

```
#s_back {
    margin-left: 3.4vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Can you try to add more vendor specific for transform property like so, not sure 100% :D

```
#s_back {
    margin-left: 3.4vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```